# Biztalk Pipelines

Tags: visual-studio-2012, biztalk, biztalk-2013

We have started using Biztalk 2013 and Visual Studio 2012. We have discovered a strange isssue with pipelines. A pipeline toolbox is empty! I have imported a pipeline from a previous project, which used Biztalk 2010 and Visual Studio 2010, and heres what i've got:

[image]

Has anyone faced this issue? Is there any fixPacks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was the .NET framework version of the BT project file issue.
Biztalk 2010 is using 4, and BT 2012 is using 4.5.
Changing it has solved the problem.